# Can't update UISlider value by its tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uislider

I have a "for" loop that translates an array to a list of UISliders. To each UISlider I attach a tag property in order to be able to change its value later on. The problem is, that every time I am trying to change the value of a specific UISlider, I get the following error:

> -[UITextField setValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146e1d270

This is the code I use to change the UISlider value by its tag:

```
UISlider *Slider = (UISlider*)[self.view viewWithTag:tagnum];
Slider.value = [textField.text floatValue]-1;
```

Thanks

Comment: The error says that you are trying to change value property on UITaxtField (But that control hasn't got that property). Are you sure the tagnum value is set up for UISilder and not for UITextField. Make sure the tag in UITextField is different than value of tagnum.

Comment: Seems like the view you are getting back from `viewWithTag:` isn't a `UISlider` but a `UITextField`. Could you add the code where you add the tags to your question ?

Comment: It's true, I am using the same tagnum on both UITextfield and UISlider. I am doing that so I can refer to a specific set of UITextfield and UISlider that are coming from the array. I am going to try something and I'll update here soon. Thanks.

Comment: SOLVED: You guys were totally right. I just had to give a unique tagnum for the UISlider in order for the view to recognize it. Thanks!

Comment: Slightly off-topic but you might want to read about [naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) if the first letter of `Slider` isn't a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you are trying to change value property on `UITextField` (But that control hasn't got that property).

Are you sure the tagnum value is set up for `UISilder` and not for `UITextField` ? Make sure the tag in `UITextField` is different than value of tagnum.